# How to schedule telegraom bot send message with pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, py-telegram-bot-api

I am using python 3.5.1 with pytelegrambotapi, and trying to set up notifications from bot, which it should send every day at particular time.

I really do not understand, how to do it, will be grateful, if someone shows me the example of a bot, that can send notifications at particular time every day to users, which r using the bot.

By now i tried to use schedule module, but the problem is,that i need to call function, that send notifications, with arguments (list of ids of users, which r using the bot), so if i try to use something like this:

```
schedule.every().day.at('17:00').do(send_test(user_id))
```

i get an error:

```
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with the telegram library, but with [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule).
The method `do` takes a function and not a result of calling a function. You can supply ther arguments taken by the function as additional arguments for `do`:

```
schedule.every().day.at('17:00').do(send_test, user_id)
```

Comment: Thank you, but now it seems, that bot is just not working:

http://pastebin.com/9a8223ay

So, if i try to write something to bot, it does nothing. I guess, it is because of the 'While' cycle in notifications function, but i don't know, how to use module schedule without it.

Comment: @mrser you need to change your function decorator to `@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)`. This will tell the module that this handler should handler every message. Read more about pytelegrambotapi [here](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)

Comment: my bot is working file, if i don't try to add notifications with schedule module, so of course i can get this example working, but it won't help me solve the problem.

Comment: @mrser your `notificitation` function never ends as it contains an `while True`-loop. So `bot.poll` will.never get called

Comment: @mrser By changing the order of `bot.polling` and `notifications` you should get it to work